# Filtering all inner text from a HTML document

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to take a large HTML document and i want to strip away all the inner text between all tags. Everything I seem to find is just about extracting text from the HTML. All I want is the raw HTML tags with their attributes intact. How would one potentially go about filtering out the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all text with `soup.find_all(text=True)`, and `.extract()` on each text element to remove it from the document:

```
for textelement in soup.find_all(text=True):
    textelement.extract()
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <html><body><p>Hello world!<p>
... <div><ul><li>This is all
... </li><li>Set to go!</li></ul></div>
... </body></html>''')
>>> soup
<html><body><p>Hello world!</p><p>
</p><div><ul><li>This is all
</li><li>Set to go!</li></ul></div>
</body></html>
>>> for textelement in soup.find_all(text=True):
...     textelement.extract()
... 
u'Hello world!'
u'\n'
u'This is all\n'
u'Set to go!'
u'\n'
>>> print soup.prettify()
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
  <div>
   <ul>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```